# Is there a word for a personal or informal definition?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What's the correct way to say something such as "my definition of good C# code is *etc.*".

I could say "I would describe good C# code as having the following attributes and adhering to the following rules: *etc.*", but that seems rather long winded.

Similarly, I often hear the expression: "The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results."  I looked up the definition of insanity, and that's not it.  If we're speaking English, the definition of a word should be its corresponding text in the dictionary.  Is there something else to call those expressions like the above examples, other than  personal or informal definitions?

Comment: Your second example is actually a quotation from Einstein; there's no reason why his definition should be worse than Webster's.

Comment: @TimLymington source?  I can't find where he claimed that as the definition of insanity, only quotes starting with "Insanity is doing..."

Comment: Last paragraph strikes me as peeving in disguise as a question.

Comment: @MetaEd At the least the last sentence is an actual question.  I added the first sentence as an example with which I am familiar.

Comment: You might be talking about humorous quips.

Comment: An informal way of expressing this is to add "-ism" to the person's name. For example, if Steve is known for using a specific word or phrase to describe some situation, you could call that a "Steve-ism." If Betty did it, it would be a "Betty-ism."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a general context, the word [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definition) does not necessarily imply a *dictionary definition*. So, your use of *"my definition of good C# code is ..."* is perfectly fine. If you want to stress that it's your personal viewpoint, you would employ the word *opinion* as follows:

> In my [personal|considered] opinion, good C# code is *defined* by ...

For an informal definition, you could use:

> A loose definition of ...

Or, if you are simplifying a definition in the interest of your audience:

> A layman's definition of ...

Answer (score 5):

First, you say "*If we're speaking English, the definition of a word should be its corresponding text in the dictionary*." but that's not really true.

There is no 'official' English dictionary since there's no 'official' definition of the English language. The English language is defined by the community that speak it and evolves over time. Dictionary-makers are just well-meaning people with expertise in lexicography who do their best to give us useful tools that reflect usage. Dictionaries are helpful, and the respectable ones carry a lot of authority - but that authority is due to the painstaking research and work that went into them, not just the virtue of being called a 'dictionary'.

Each of us is free to make our own definitions that fit the context we're dealing with. "Definitions" are just explanations of a word's meaning using some paraphrase. What really matters is communication and being understood.

That all said - if you say **"*the* definition of good C++ code"**, the use of the definite article means you are referring to a particular definition. It may be Webster's or Stroustrup's. If you say **"*my* definition of good C++ code"**, then it's clear that you are referring to a personal definition which may not be found in a published book.

Comment: @Mehper When I quoted the original, it had "it's". I see it's been fixed now... :)

Comment: No worries.. :)

Comment: Not only are we free to make our own definitions, we're also free to use words without attaching any definitions to them at all, and that's what we do in the vast majority of cases. I think we usually effectively decide whether a word is appropriate based analogies with how it was used in the past, not by using any definition.

Answer (score 0):

How about *operational definition*? The term is defined in terms of how it is being used/ or described in your report/presentation/paper.

Answer (score 0):

You might say **"My *standard* for good C++ code..."**

Standards vary according to the situation and the requirements. Having said that, they should be consistent under similar conditions (or they wouldn't be standards). In your case, you may have good reasons to *define* your own standard.

Comment: I personally prefer to avoid such senses of *standard* in technical contexts, because discussions about what is and isn't standard in the specific sense of adhering to a particular specification published by a standards body, are so common that other senses of the word can confuse things.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed time and again how technical-minded people (being one myself) do get hung up (boxed in) with words. I would have offered "policy" as an alternative. Policies seem to be more local, standards (even *my* standards) tend to be given a global interpretation.

Comment: It's not even so much a matter of hung up, as that one can end up with statements where its not clear which sense is meant, but the distinction makes for a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

**The word you are looking for is "aphorism"** derived from the Greek word meaning "definition".  The modern cultural artifact we call a "dictionary" is based on one interpretation of how to define a word's meaning. The current approach is based primarily on a philosophy of use - that a word means whatever its users use it to mean.  This leaves out much useful information, which could be based on the kind of tacit knowledge Polanyi called "personal knowledge" (Michal Polanyi, "Personal knowledge") A definition attempts to clarify a field of meaning. The questioner should be free to share his tacit and explicit knowledge of programming. The degree to which people will accept it as a definition may depend on the degree to which it identifies and clarifies the important features.

Comment: Hi, Robert. Welcome to the stack. This is a good answer, but it could be [improved](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) by linking to supporting documentation. Please [take the tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and enjoy contributing. :)

Comment: That's not the default definition of 'aphorism' and not one I've found in several dictionaries. If redefining terms, one needs to make it clear that one is departing from standard usage. ELU deals with standard usages; stating baldly 'You want X' can be worse than unhelpful.